# MariaDB - complex trigger query after update

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I have three tables  ( *restaurants - votes - comments*) . I want to create  a trigger which let me update two fields in restaurants ( *restaurant_rate_average , restaurant_comment_count* ) . Here is my trigger :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `change comment status` AFTER UPDATE ON `comments` 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

       UPDATE restaurants
       INNER JOIN votes ON restaurants.restaurant_id = votes.vote_foreign_key
       SET restaurants.restaurant_comment_count = SELECT (COUNT(votes.vote_id))
       WHERE votes.vote_model = 'restaurant'
       AND WHERE old.comment_status<>NEW.comment_status;

       UPDATE restaurants
       INNER JOIN votes ON restaurants.restaurant_id = votes.vote_foreign_key
       SET restaurants.restaurant_rate_average = SELECT (AVG(votes.vote_num))
       WHERE votes.vote_model = 'restaurant'
       AND WHERE old.comment_status<>NEW.comment_status;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Actually I have an error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT (COUNT(votes.vote_id))
       WHERE votes.vote_model = 'restaurant'
      ' at line 8
```

I've tried to make complexion less and replace SELECT (COUNT(votes.vote_id)) with 2 and I get new error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE comments.comment_status<>NEW.comment_status;

       UPDATE resta' at line 9
```

How to resolve it?

**EDITED :**

here is my pseudo tables :

**restaurants:** 
restaurant_id, restaurant_comment_count(int) , restaurant_rate_average(int)

**comments:**
comment_id , comment_status(boolean) , comment_content(varchar) , votes_vote_id(id)

**votes:**
vote_id , vote_foreign_key(id), vote_model(varchar)

**EDITED 2 :**

I create new simple trigger which just join three tables and it works like charm:

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE restaurants res
   INNER JOIN votes v ON v.vote_foreign_key = res.restaurant_id AND v.vote_foreign_key = 'restaurant'
   INNER JOIN comments cm ON cm.votes_vote_id = v.vote_id
   SET res.restaurant_rate_average = 2
   WHERE cm.comment_status = NEW.comment_status;
END
```

But if I replace *SET res.restaurant_rate_average = 2* with  *SELECT AVG(v.vote_id)* I got an error. I also edit last trigger to :

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE RESTAURANT_RATE_AVERAGE INTEGER;
   SET RESTAURANT_RATE_AVERAGE := (SELECT AVG(votes.vote_num)
   UPDATE restaurants res
   INNER JOIN votes v ON v.vote_foreign_key = res.restaurant_id AND v.vote_foreign_key = 'restaurant'
   INNER JOIN comments cm ON cm.votes_vote_id = v.vote_id
   SET restaurant_rate_average = RESTAURANT_RATE_AVERAGE
   WHERE cm.comment_status = NEW.comment_status;
END
```

I got an error in line 4. All I want is replace static number with `SELECT AVG(votes.vote_num)`

Comment: please post your tables

Comment: Your `WHERE` clauses don't make any sense.  They are referring to the `comment_status` column which belongs the `comments` table, but this table is not part of the join.

Comment: @e4c5 I updated my question

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how to resolve it?

Comment: For starters, get the basic three way join working outside your trigger, e.g. in Workbench.  If you can't even do that, there is no point in attempting to write a trigger.  You will need to join `votes` and `comments` using the `vote_id` column (not my downvote).

Comment: The tables you have posted isn't any use to us. Anyone wanting to try out your query would need to spend a lot of time and effort manually creating the tables. Why couldn't you just use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: @e4c5 The bigger problem in my mind is that the queries are broken, and the logic he wants to use is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: true @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score -1):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_comment_status`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `update_comment_status` AFTER UPDATE ON `comments` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   DECLARE RESTAURANT_RATE_AVERAGE INTEGER;
   DECLARE RESTAURANT_COMMENT_COUNT INTEGER;
   SET RESTAURANT_RATE_AVERAGE := (SELECT AVG(votes.vote_num) FROM votes);
   UPDATE restaurants res
   INNER JOIN votes v ON v.vote_foreign_key = res.restaurant_id AND v.vote_foreign_key = 'restaurant'
   INNER JOIN comments cm ON cm.votes_vote_id = v.vote_id
   SET restaurant_rate_average = RESTAURANT_RATE_AVERAGE
   WHERE cm.comment_status = NEW.comment_status;

   SET RESTAURANT_COMMENT_COUNT := (SELECT COUNT(votes.vote_id) FROM  votes);
      UPDATE restaurants res
   INNER JOIN votes v ON v.vote_foreign_key = res.restaurant_id AND v.vote_foreign_key = 'restaurant'
   INNER JOIN comments cm ON cm.votes_vote_id = v.vote_id
   SET restaurant_comment_count = RESTAURANT_COMMENT_COUNT
   WHERE cm.comment_status = NEW.comment_status;

END
```

Comment: The `AVG` and `COUNT` are over _all_ restaurants.  This seems 'wrong'.